# panoramic x-ray normalization in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, x-ray

I have this screenshot of an x-ray image in a jupyter notebook:

[image: screenshot]

and after applying normalization in this code

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np

X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], -1))
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], -1))

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], 224, 224,3))
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], 224, 224,3))

print(X_train.shape)
```

the x-ray image appears like that

[image]

is that normal?

I tried to normalize my x-ray images for the model can easily predict the results

Comment: By applying Sciki-Learn's StandardScaler you are computing the standard score of the image... Which doesn't make sense, you are just messing up the contrast and brightness. You just need to Min-Max scale it to bring the data type range to [0,1]. Just dividing the image by 255.0 usually works.

Comment: See skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(). It has 'image' mode for input to find the min and max values and you can set the output range to (0,1).